# Htaccess RewriteRule trouble - How to redirect to a "re-written" url on the server?

Tags: url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following rewrite rule which is working fine:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\-]+)[/]?$ apply/?survey_folder=$1
```

which turns this: `address.com/folder1/`
into this: `address.com/apply/?survey_folder=folder1`

The problem is that I can't figure out a way to use a redirect to the rewritten URL. Using cfml as an example, (cflocation url="http://www.address.com/folder1/") throws an error because, of course, the folder "folder1" doesn't actually exist on the server.

I can get the user redirected to the correct page by using /apply/?survey_folder=folder1, but that defeats the purpose of having the rewrite rule at all.

Is there any way to redirect to a URL rewritten by htaccess? I'm new at RewriteRule.

Answer (score 1):

Add the [L] flag to the rule otherwise you're in danger of infinite loops and other problems.

The redirect you need is incredibly simple.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /apply/(index\.php)?\?survey_folder=([\ ]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^apply/(index\.php)? http://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Z-]+)$ /apply/?survey_folder=$1 [NC,L]
```

Do not let both URLs with trailing slash and URLs without trailing slash resolve to the same content. The URL for a page does not have a trailing slash. Add another preceding redirect to strip trailing slashes in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `RewriteBase`?  Its purpose is to map the URL to the physical location on the server.  I'm not completely sure this is the problem you are having, but it does sound like a possibility.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I read your link and decided it wasn't quite what I was looking for because I would need to have a base path for each different folder (of which, there could be thousands). I went back and tried things again and it appears to work perfectly fine to do a redirect to a rewritten URL. I must have just had a typo somewhere. I appreciate your help though!